# ARM processor based board for beginners

Tags: multithreading, arm, rtos, toolchain, jtag

1. I want to buy a ARM microprocessor based board, Can any one tell
   which is the best(in terms of functionality) and cost effective?
2. What hardware/Software tools and cables I need to buy (For
   debugging, IDE, etc)?

(**Note:** *Multi-thread code to be tested, RTOS (Linux, ThreadX etc), Hardware debugging*)

Comment: if you want linux (which is not an rtos), then raspberry pi or beaglebone.  the raspberry pi is limited in its I/O but easy on the budget.  If linux is not a requirement you can get things like the stellaris launchpad or the stm32f4 discovery or the f0 discovery, etc.

Comment: There is no such thing as BEST, you shouldnt use words like that in a forum like this.  Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: with the raspberry pi you probably want a usb to uart/serial (some flavor of 3.3v ftdi board) as well as monitor keyboard, etc.  This is good in general.  beaglebone you dont really need anything, stellaris, you might want a ftdi board, but might not need it at all.  same goes for the stm32 discovery boards, I think you can get uart through the usb to the host.  boards like the mbed you definitely can.

Comment: software is all free, codesourcery or https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded or roll your own (or get an extra raspberry pi and just develop natively on that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go for `lpc2xxx` series from `nxp`.  It has got ARM7 core.
2. Software - `keil` is good. `jtag` debugger can be used for debugging.

Comment: ARM7 (ARMv4) is not really a good architecture to run linux on.

Comment: Thank you Mark, Kulkarni and user2050283

Answer (score 1):

There are several options based on your budget and what you want to do with it. If you want to run Linux, you'll need something substantial. I recommend the [Raspberry-Pi](http://downloads.element14.com/raspberryPi1.html?COM=raspi-group). It has a good online community and Linux ports.